# WYSIWYG for javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-editor, form-designer

I know the term "what you see is what you get" cannot be realy applied to javascript, but I am curious if is there any IDE which helps you generate JavaScript sourcecode by visualy designing it. It doesn't matter the framework, if any, used.

I speak about something like the form designer in Visual Studio.

Comment: If you're talking about something similar to Animation in Powerpoint, then no. At least, I haven't come across such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking might be near impossible since Javascript is such a dynamic language. The closest I've seen is Aptana's object browser or maybe something like ctags integrated into your favorite editor. But these things build a navigable textual outline, not something that's "graphical."

While Aptana is about as good as you can get, you still run into the issue of callback functions. Callback functions usually aren't named and how do you layout/navigate stuff without names (sure, you could do shapes/symbols/etc but that'd probably be difficult)?

Perhaps you're talking about something like [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)? If so, I don't know of any UML to code editors. That would be kind of cool, though. At least, when starting a project. Might be hard to navigate when the code gets huge, I would guess.

Or, perhaps you're talking about something like VisualStudio or Xcode - where you layout the interface and have code connected to it. Xcode's [Dashcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashcode) kind of does this, but I think it only works with it's own custom SDK - I'm not sure if you can use pure Javascript.